# Upload file Crashes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

Tell me please, whats wrong in my code. When i attempt to get posted file in controller it throws index out of range exception:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", new { enctype = "mulitipart/form-data" }))
   {%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>

        <br>
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

<% } %>
```

Controller method:

```
public ActionResult Upload(){
var r = Request.Files[0];  //here i got an exception    
        byte[] b=new byte[r.ContentLength];
        r.InputStream.Read(b, 0, r.ContentLength);
        ...................................
```

Comment: Messing with `enctype` and `Request.Files`? Ouch. You need to un-learn Web Forms and learn some MVC.

Comment: Do you have separate GET and POST actions? The GET should display your view and you should put the code that is inspecting the Request.Files property in your POST action.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it might just be a spelling mistake ... where you have `mulitipart/form-data` should be `multipart/form-data` ... you have an extra "i" in there.